# How to load a project into QGIS with PyQGIS?

Tags: python, qgis

I am leaning PyQGIS using the PyQGIS Cookbook and I purchased the PyQGIS Programmers Guide.  I have been able to load layers ok using little scripts but no luck loading a project into QGIS.  I keep getting a 'SyntaxError: invalid syntax' for line 13.  I am using the Python Console inside QGIS and type in 'import _loadproject' to start the script.

Can someone point out where I am going wrong?

```
"""Load Project: This is to test loading a project."""

from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.utils import iface

class ProjectScript:

def __init__(self, iface):
    self.iface = iface

def load_project(self)
    project = QgsProject.instance() \
    project.read(QFileInfo('S:/SOCAL/Section_28/SOCAL_CK47/Control_Data/SOCAL_CK47_project.qgs'))
    print project.fileName 'S:/SOCAL/Section_28/SOCAL_CK47/Control_Data/SOCAL_CK47_project.qgs'

def run_script(iface):
"""Run the script by loading and calling LoadProject methods."""
fs = ProjectScript(iface)
fs.load_project()
```

Comment: in line 13 you don't have ":" in load_project function "def load_project(self):"

Answer (score 1):

Check this example:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.utils import iface

class ProjectScript:

    def __init__(self, iface):
        self.iface = iface

    def load_project(self):
        project = QgsProject.instance() 
        project.read(QFileInfo('S:\\SOCAL\\Section_28\\SOCAL_CK47\\Control_Data\\SOCAL_CK47_project.qgs'))
        print project.fileName()

    def run_script(iface):
        """Run the script by loading and calling LoadProject methods."""
        fs = ProjectScript(iface)
        fs.load_project()
```

Save this script ,for example **ProjectScript.py** using the python Console,and execute.The next image show the result.[image]

Comment: Thank you! - It's funny the script works in the Script Runner plug-in but not using the QGIS console.  I will dig in deeper.  But one additional question -   when I load a project manually I always get the name of the project in the top left corner of QGIS (Example: QGIS 2.18.2  -  SOCAL_CK47_project), but not when I run the script.  Is there a statement I can use to refresh QGIS to show the project name?

Comment: try with this : qgis.utils.iface.mainWindow().setWindowTitle("My Title")